# java 11 jvm doesn't choose the right method when the parameter is returned by a generic method

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I have an issue in my project while switched to java 11. A problem is:
I have an interface

```
public interface InterfaceA {}
```

a child class

```
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {}
```

and generic method

```
private final Map<String, InterfaceA> h = new HashMap<>();
public <T extends InterfaceA> T get(String key) {
  return (T) h.get(key);
}
```

Now when I call, for example a StringBuilder append method:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append(get("KeyString")); //call StringBuilder.append(CharSequence) method
```

I get a ClassCastException at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class ClassA cannot be cast to class java.lang.CharSequence
```

When I cast the return value

```
sb.append((ClassA)get("KeyString")); //call StringBuilder.append(Object) method
```

It works!

The question is why choose the jvm the wrong method?

```
StringBuilder.append(CharSequence);
```

instead of

```
StringBuilder.append(Object);
```

I don't want to implement CharSequence interface. In earlier it works with java 8. Now I don't want to cast every single call in my code, because there are 1000+ places in the whole code.

I've the same issue with HashMap.put method.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I get a compiler error: and not a `ClassCastException`: `Ambiguous method call. Both append(String) in StringBuilder and append(StringBuffer) in StringBuilder match`.

Comment: You're right, if the generic definition is in the same project. But if the generic definition in another dependency, then the compiler doesn't know exactly the type. The question is why?!  Why it works in java 8 and why not in 11?